# Fast image search engine

Tags: image, solr, elasticsearch, search-engine, httpresponse

I've looked all over, but haven't found a satisfactory guide/explanation on coming up with an image search server (though [this](http://solr.pl/en/2012/02/20/simple-photo-search/) gives a starting point). I want to set up a [Concept based image indexing system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_based_image_indexing) (basically, a standard image search engine accepting text queries) with any off-the-rack text search solution like Solr, Elastic Search etc. (Only a suggestion. Any other solutions are equally welcome). So, images (indexed on name, tags, authorship etc.) would be served up as response to standard text queries and rendered on the client as results.

These are my requirements and/or assumptions:

- The images themselves are small (thumbnail sized).
- The system should be really fast/responsive (think auto query completion on a search engine).
- I know that browsers make individual request for each image rendered, but I would like to have the images be part of the response itself (save network calls to retrieve each image).
- All images are pre-processed. No image manipulation necessary at query time.

Could Apache Tika with Solr be a feasible solution ? I don't fully understand it, but will it index images as binary content ?

An important concern here is the organization of the image files themselves on the server (Flat or directory based ? How do I come up with an efficient image hosting solution ?)

I can visualize a system where I index meta-information for each image on Solr and then serve the URL of the image as a response, leaving it to the client to retrieve and render the image. But I'm apprehensive as to whether this solution would meet the speed and responsiveness requirements (Images should render as the user types her query) ?

I realize that parts of my question are vague, but hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.semanticmetadata.net/lire/ is based on lucene. For solr integration : https://bitbucket.org/dermotte/liresolr

Comment: I want **Concept** based image recognition, not Content based. Basically, a simple search engine which will index text description of the image. But my main requirement is speed, so wanted to know if solr(or anything else) can store the image itself (as binary data). Which option is faster ?- Sending the images embedded in the response or just sending the links back as the response and letting the browser download them individually ?

Comment: Ah I see, If you have rights to save a copy of images in your disk, I would save them locally. Index their paths and associated text in Solr. By the way solr has binary field. Probably you can